# JLabel not updating while in while loop

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, event-dispatch-thread

I am very new to programming and I was wondering if you guys knew the answer to this. I am using the AWT gui and I am trying to make a program that reads text files to you word by word at a fast pace to train you to read faster. The problem is that the JLabel that is supposed to show the words one at a time is not updating. Thank you all in advance and I apologize if my code is hard to read or messy.

```
package fastreader; 
// this is a program where you input a location of a text file and it will read the file to you one word at a time very fast.

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author S578748
 */
public class FastReader implements ActionListener{
    //Frame
    private static JFrame frame;            
    //Panel
    private static JPanel selectPanel;      
    //Buttons
    private static JButton enterButton;  
    //Labels
    private static JLabel selectFile;
    public static JLabel readLabel;
    //TextField
    private static JTextField fileLocation;
    //Strings
    public static String file;
    public static String word;
    public static String data;
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        selectPanel = new JPanel();
        enterButton = new JButton();
        
        frame.setSize(450, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(selectPanel);
        
        selectPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        selectFile = new JLabel("Enter Location of File");
        selectFile.setBounds(10, 20, 160, 25);
        selectPanel.add(selectFile);
        
        fileLocation = new JTextField();
        fileLocation.setBounds(200, 20, 160, 25);
        selectPanel.add(fileLocation);
        
        enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
        enterButton.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        enterButton.addActionListener(new FastReader());
        selectPanel.add(enterButton);
        
        readLabel = new JLabel("");
        readLabel.setBounds(10, 60, 160, 25);
        selectPanel.add(readLabel);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    
    //Action Field if Button is Pressed
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Getting the file location from the TextField.
        file = fileLocation.getText();
        Scanner s = null;
            try{
                s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FastReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                data = s.nextLine();
                
                while(data.contains(" ")){
                    word = data.substring(0,data.indexOf(" ")); // this splits the lines into words.
                    data = data.substring(data.indexOf(" ")+1);
                    
                    readLabel.setText(word); // this is where it messes up, it is supposed to change the JLabel in the program but it doesn't seem to update.
                    
                    if(word.length()<3){
                        try {
                            sleep(100); // these timers are supposed to create a delay where you can read the word.
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(FastReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                        
                    else if(word.length()<6){
                        try {
                            sleep(200);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(FastReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else{
                        try {
                            sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(FastReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }                       
                    } 
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
                readLabel.setText(data);
            }    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Swing is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed in the Event Dispatcher Thread 
([EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). 
Running long processes (such as sleep) on the EDT makes keeps this thread busy, so it does not do other things 
like updating the gui. The gui becomes unresponsive (freezes).
Also you do not want to construct a new instance of `FastReader` every time the button is clicked. Use `enterButton.addActionListener(this)`

Comment: 1) Usage of `null layout` is heavily discouraged. Read about [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and how to use them. 2) I'm no expert on multi-threading so I'll suggest a perhaps simpler approach. Reading the file definitely works as the console prints `word` just fine. You could split the two actions of collecting the data and displaying it by filling a list with your `word` Strings in your current thread and once the whole file is read and the data is collected you could then iterate over the list to update your Label.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is a little bit technical. Java's AWT framework has only one thread to update the UI and that thread is being hogged by the while loop and the `sleep` calls you are making in your implementation of the `actionPerformed` method. One solution is to wrap it all inside a thread

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            // here goes your current code
        }).start();
    }
```

This is assuming you are using at least Java 8 it can be done in other versions with different syntax.
Hope it helps.